# Node Is not reading collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
at .<anonymous> (/Library/WebServer/Documents/nodeprojects/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:313:35)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at emit (events.js:188:7)
at .<anonymous> (/Library/WebServer/Documents/nodeprojects/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:260:12)
at g (events.js:286:16)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at emit (events.js:191:7)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Library/WebServer/Documents/nodeprojects/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:162:49)
at Socket.g (events.js:286:16)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at connectErrorNT (net.js:1015:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect' }
/Library/WebServer/Documents/nodeprojects/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:225
          throw err
          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of null
    at /Library/WebServer/Documents/nodeprojects/server.js:30:29
    at connectCallback (/Library/WebServer/Documents/nodeprojects/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:315:5)
    at /Library/WebServer/Documents/nodeprojects/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:222:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

Comment: you need to start mongo server then only you will be able to connect. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#id6

Comment: Hi I already start mongo and mongod its showing me all table

Comment: Did you try to give your mongodb ur `127.0.0.1 instead localhost`?

Comment: @abdulbarik Thanks bro its working fine but some time its working with localhost

Comment: Glad it works, cheers!!!